# = sign at the end of .sock files in the ls output

Tags: ls, socket

I'm running the zsh shell in emacs. When I run `ls` I get a `=` at the end of `.sock` files. What does the `=` mean? Is it unique to unix sockets?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html) documentation under `--classify` (alias `-F`), 
`=` is for sockets:

> Append a character to each file name indicating the file type. Also, for regular files that are executable, append ‘*’. The file type indicators are ‘/’ for directories, ‘@’ for symbolic links, ‘|’ for FIFOs, ‘=’ for sockets, ‘>’ for doors, and nothing for regular files. Do not follow symbolic links listed on the command line unless the --dereference-command-line (-H), --dereference (-L), or --dereference-command-line-symlink-to-dir options are specified.

Comment: Neato, thank you. Never heard of doors as a formal name before.

Comment: and if you didn't actually type `--classify` or `--indicator-style=classify`, it was probably added by an alias.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian [Doors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doors_(computing)) are a Solaris feature, not widely adopted, and in particular not available on Linux.

Comment: If anyone has enough rep for a 1-character edit, there's now an https version of the URL in this answer.